# On demand combo and asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how to develop a ondeman combo which behave like when user click on arrow button of the combo then 10 records as content will load in the combo and show and when user scroll down the combo then again 10 record will show and display. at the bottom end of the combo the will pagination system like next prev. please advise me to how to develop this type of combo in asp.net....thanks

Comment: What have you tried or looked for? Are you trying to implement this based on something you've seen, at least I can't really make out what you are trying to accomplish? AFAIK you don't really have any events sent from a combobox (so there's nothing telling you that the user scrolled to the bottom of it) meaning you can't really act upon anything.